# How to draw a circle and move it / drag it on touch in IOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uiview

I would like to draw a circle programmatically and give user ability to be able to drag it. Is this possible in IOS? This will be on an iPad app.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, it's both possible and relatively simple, but it doesn't make sense for us to write down the answers here when you can read them in Apple's documentation. From the [faq]: *Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could create a custom `UIView` and overwrite it's `drawRect` method to draw the circle. The `drawRect` method would then look like this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [[UIColor redColor] CGColor]);
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, self.bounds);
}
```

Don't forget to set the views background color to the clear color.

To handle the movement, add a gesture recognizer to the custom view (for you possibly a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`) and handle its events (there are plenty of examples on how to do this).

Comment: thx for taking time and answering my question.

Comment: But this one would have a problem with collision where a circle under another circle will not be selected instead the on over the top of it.